# 2nd HDD not showing up in "My Computer". Using SSD as main drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, sata, setup

I just set up my new computer. Built it from scratch. This is my second machine I built so it's not a hobby I'm very proficient at yet.

I have a 60gb SSD and a 1.5 TB HD

In bios I set up my SSD over my HDD. It registered in bios then. Not sure if I was supposed to do anything else while in bios.

When I downloaded windows 7. The OS asked me what HD to use. My HDD was labeled sata0 and my SSD was labeled sata1. I wanted to make the SSD my boot drive so I chose SSD. Windows finished installing and I was about to install drivers and saw that under my computer I only have drive C, my SSD. I don't see my big HDD anywhere. What did I mess up?

Comment: My HDD is a Samsung 154UI 1.5 TB

Comment: Where did you download Windows 7 from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the disk is in your device manager all you need to do is go to `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Disk Management` find your disk and make sure it is it has a "Healthy Active Primary Partition" and not "Unallocated".  Make it active and/or format it if it reads "Unallocated".  Remember if you choose to format you will be erasing all data on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk is in your device manager all you need to do is go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Disk Management. check if it has a letter e.g (G:) etc.